# Dialog modal is not working in asp.net core mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

I'm Developing an ASP.NET Core web application & stuck in a problem regarding the Bootstrap dialog modal. I just want to load a `partialView` into a dialog modal on a button click & have implemented it in the code. But the problem is Dialog modal is not getting appear, instead page gets refreshes with instant dark splash.

It is very strange, because I have implemented modals previously too.

Here is my code in `View.cshtml`

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <section class="content">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="box box-success">
                <div class="box-header">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Add Queue</h3>
                </div>
                <form asp-action="Create">
                    <div class="box-body">
                        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                           @* ....... *@
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            @* ...... *@
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            @* ...... *@
                            @* ---- button that triggers the modal ---- *@
                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#adHocAdd">Add New</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="box-footer">
                        <input type="submit" value="Next" class="btn btn-primary" />
                        <input type="reset" value="Clear" class="btn btn-warning" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

@* ------- modal div ---------- *@
<div id="adHocAdd" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Create a New Menu</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @**Load View*@
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: can you see the modal even for a second?? or is it completely not working??

Comment: No I cant see a modal getting popup here.. but web page gets darker for mili second time & url gets refresh..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be due to your button is within the `<form>` tag. In ASP.NET I also have experienced this problem.

To overcome the problem you can add `type="button"` inside your `<Button>` tag & run the code. so your full code for button will be looks like following.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#adHocAdd">Add New</button>
```

According to my point of view, this problem is due to triggering of form submission on the button click which launches the model.

For further understanding purpose refer here ([dotnetfiddle.net](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k0nTS8)).

- There are 2 buttons, one with same as in above problem, & other button is with `type="button"` respectively.
- Button without `type="button"` will appear & get disappear within seconds. But other one will remain as normal.

Comment: Great! Simple explanation & wonderful demo in the [https://dotnetfiddle.net/k0nTS8](https://dotnetfiddle.net/k0nTS8) . Appriciate your work

Answer (score 0):

A button inside a form will always act as submit if nothing is specified. So either you keep the form inside the model body or remove the model from the form and keep it outside of it.

Here the button is not only triggering the Model but is also submitting the form. So before your model appears, you are doing the post.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip.. !! That was the problem